# MySQL Warning 1264 Out of Range Value for DateTime

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, datetime

I am trying to insert a datetime from a C# program textbox to a MySQL database.  Every time I run the program in Visual Studio, I get the error:

> "Fatal error encountered during command execution."

I tried running the query in MySQL to get a more specific response and received a warning 1264 out of range value error.  The date appears to be in the proper format and I am converting to datetime before it is sent to MySQL.  I have also checked my database column data type which is set to datetime.  Why would I still be receiving this error?

```
string sqlInsertBackup = "insert into backups (tape_num, bup_type, bup_date, bup_release, completed, date_created, date_modified) values (@tape_num, @backupType, @startDate, @releaseDate, 0, now(), now())";
MySqlCommand cmdInsertBackup = new MySqlCommand(sqlInsertBackup, idb.myconn);
cmdInsertBackup.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tapeNum", tapeNum);
cmdInsertBackup.Parameters.AddWithValue("@backupType", backupType);
cmdInsertBackup.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startDate", System.Convert.ToDateTime(startDate));
cmdInsertBackup.Parameters.AddWithValue("@releaseDate", System.Convert.ToDateTime(releaseDate));
cmdInsertBackup.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first parameter is named `@tape_num` not `@tapeNum`, so it hasn't been given a value.

Comment: Truly a 'herp derp' moment on my part.  Thank you!